# How to put avatar image in the navbar?

Tags: materialize

I have a dropdown section in the navbar. I would like to put an avatar image just before the username or replace it.

```
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">{{user.username}}<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a>
    </li>
```

[image]
I've tried putting an image tag with the class of responsive image but the image is too big and it exceeds navbar section

```
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">
            <img class="responsive-img" src="media/default.jpg">
            {{user.username}}<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
        </a>
    </li>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What issues are you having?

Answer (score 0):

You can move {{user.username}} into span tag and add image tag before username. Please check below code

```
<li>
  <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">
    <img src="avatar-image_path">
    <span>{{user.username}}</span>
    <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
  </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works tough the image goes out of the area of navbar. How should I control the size of the image and align it in the center of the navbar

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the image size issue with CSS styling. Haven't found a way to show username with an offset yet.

**Final code**

```
    <!-- Dropdown Trigger -->
    <li>
        <a class="dropdown-trigger" href="#!" data-target="dropdown1">
            <!-- <span class="left">{{user.username}}</span> -->
            <i class="valign-wrapper">
                <img src="media/default.jpg" alt="logo" style="height: 28px;" class="responsive-img circle valign-wrapper">
                <i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i>
            </i>      
        </a>
    </li>
```